# UK visa for trailer driver non-EU citizens

Tags: schengen, uk, indian-citizens, work

I'm living in Spain with 2-year residence card and an Indian passport. As I'm a international trailer driver I drive through approximately all Schengen countries. My company also move goods from Spain to the UK and UK to Spain. For this purpose I need a UK visa to enter the UK.

So I want to know in which category and subcategory UK visa should I apply for?  I've searched the  UK visa section I don't get any clue for truck driver visa. If this is in work visa category or transit visa category then next in which subcategory?

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're not going to *live* in the UK, and you won't be working for anyone except your Spanish employer, you don't need a work visa -- a **Standard Visitor** visa will do.

Transporting goods into and out of the UK by road is considered a "business purpose". Or at least transporting goods *into* the UK is, according to paragraph 21(c) of Appendix 3 to the [Visitor Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf):

> Individuals employed outside the UK may visit the UK to take part in the following activities in relation to their employment overseas:
>   (...)
>   (c) a driver on a genuine international route delivering goods or passengers from abroad to the UK;

Reading this strictly it can appear that a visitor visa is not valid for entering the UK with an empty truck for the purpose of delivering goods from the UK to abroad. On the other hand such an interpretation would seem to fly in the face of common sense -- but bureaucratic regulations sometimes do that, so it might be a good idea to ask explicitly at your interview whether such a run would be a permitted use of the visa.

Comment: +1, small nitpick. They would not interview the OP. It would be a paper decision only.  Otherwise stellar answer!

Comment: @GayotFow: Hmm, the information at https://uk.tlscontact.com/es/mad/page.php?pid=procedure seems to say that visa applicants need to book and attend a personal appointment with an agent.

Comment: Yeah, that's to turn their stuff in to the Visa Application Centre. They are not caseworkers at the VAC, and they do not interview applicants.  They just look at all the OP's stuff and put it in a large envelope.  In fact, they are forbidden to profess any sort of expertise on visa specifics.  The OP will never see or be interviewed by an ECO