# What kind of visa is needed for goods vehicle transport for non-EU citizen from Malta to the UK?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, malta

I am from India. I am working in Malta as a truck driver.

Now my company is planning regular trips from Malta to the UK. What kind of visa do I need to apply for this?

Comment: Do you have an international road hauliers operators licence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa for trailer driver non-EU citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48506/uk-visa-for-trailer-driver-non-eu-citizens)

Comment: Through what countries will you be driving?

Comment: My friends thanks for your replays .sorry about it i try to find out that way but i cant get any genuine answer also that question 4 years before now its totally change .I have simple suggestion too much drivers passing same way so if anyone ask the driver what kind of visa they have they can give you answer.I  go embassy but they told me ask the visa possessing center .TLS they dont have any contact number here in Malta.When i go where they are working in hotel they are telling without booking I cant meet them.if i 
want a booking first i submit My visa application and paid for it.

Comment: Then i call help line in UK.they are also not give a information they told me search online UK government website my 5 Euro going for my Accountl because its a paid service for making fooling people.Really i hope someone here they can understand my situation here.Thanks